# PHP Foreach Loop not using break

Tags: php, arrays, loops

I want to create this loop

```
<li class="royalSlide">
    <div class="celebFixSlider">
        <a href=""><img src="" /></a>
        <a href=""><img src="" /></a>
        <a href=""><img src="" /></a>
        <a href=""><img src="" /></a>
        <a href=""><img src="" /></a>
        <a href=""><img src="" /></a>
    </div>
</li>

<li class="royalSlide">
    <div class="celebFixSlider">
        <a href=""><img src="" /></a>
        <a href=""><img src="" /></a>
        <a href=""><img src="" /></a>
        <a href=""><img src="" /></a>
        <a href=""><img src="" /></a>
        <a href=""><img src="" /></a>
    </div>
</li>
```

The LI and DIV elements are the first loop, the links are 6 row blocks per the Array.

```
$imagePath="//site.com/images/celeb1208/";
$productPath="//site.com/product.php?prodref=";
$array = array(
    "632_white" => "celeb1208_317_large.jpg",
     "631_white" => "celeb1208_316_large.jpg",
     "630_white" => "celeb1208_315_large.jpg",
     "629_white" => "celeb1208_314_large.jpg",
     "628_white" => "celeb1208_313_large.jpg",
     "627_white" => "celeb1208_312_large.jpg",
     "532_white" => "celeb1208_311_large.jpg",
     "531_white" => "celeb1208_310_large.jpg",
     "530_white" => "celeb1208_309_large.jpg",
     "529_white" => "celeb1208_308_large.jpg",
     "528_white" => "celeb1208_307_large.jpg",
     "527_white" => "celeb1208_306_large.jpg"
);

$i=0;
foreach ($array as $key => $val)
{      
  $i++; 

        echo '
        <li class="royalSlide">
            <div class="celebFixSlider">
                <a href="'.$productPath.''.$key.'">
                <img src="'.$val.'" />
        </a>';
       if($i==6){
            echo '</div>
            </li>';
            break;            
        }

}
```

After 6 items, the break just stops the code, it does not pause and recreate the loop within side?? Sorry if I am not clear.

Comment: it works as it should, what is your question then?

Comment: So you want to create a new `<ul>` every 6 `<li>`s?

Comment: You are not clear... Anyway, break is doing [what it's supposed to](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.break.php): exiting the loop.

Comment: what are you trying to achieve with this good. please explain in details. break statement will cause to exit from the for loop as well. what do you expect??,

Comment: I want to create the block of code above, so it creates a LI and DIV with 6 items every 6

Comment: @theblack: but doing it this way will open 6 li/div sets for every **1** set that you close. you'll end up with hideously mangled html due  to the open/close mismatch

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
// getting data ready
foreach ($array as $key => $val) {
  $array[$key] = array(
    "href" => $productPath.$key,
    "img"  => $imagePath.$val
  );
}
$data = array_chunk($array,2);

// printing it out
?>
<?php foreach ($data as $array): ?>
<li class="royalSlide">
    <div class="celebFixSlider">
<?php   foreach ($array as $row): ?>
        <a href="<?=$row['href']?>"><img src="<?=$row['img']?>" /></a>
<?php   endforeach ?>
    </div>
</li>
<?php endforeach ?>
```

Comment: Like the name change. And this is some smart code, cant believe I did not approach it like this.

Comment: Aha thanks. It's always hard to spot these typos when writing in the textarea without running the code :)

Answer (score 3):

The `break;` command will stop the loop completly.  Maybe you want `continue;` that will skip what is after the continue keyword and loop again from where it left off.

What you need is no break and no continue.:

```
$i=0;
echo '<li class="royalSlide"><div class="celebFixSlider">';
foreach ($array as $key => $val)
{
  $i++;
    echo '
            <a href="'.$productPath.''.$key.'">
            <img src="'.$val.'" />
    </a>';
   if($i==6){
        echo '</div>
        </li><li class="royalSlide"><div class="celebFixSlider">';
    }

}
echo '</div></li>';
```

Comment: `continue` doesn't make much more sense than `break` at this point. Actually, it makes less sense since it's a no-op in this case.

Answer (score 2):

Use "continue" instead of "break";

Break will stop the loop

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try this for your loop instead

```
$i=0;
foreach ($array as $key => $val)
{      
  $i++;
  if(($i % 6) == 0){
    echo '<li class="royalSlide"><div class="celebFixSlider">';
  }

  echo '<a href="'.$productPath.''.$key.'"><img src="'.$val.'" /></a>';

  if(($i % 6) == 0 && $i!=0){
    echo '</div></li>';
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

So you should use this:

```
 echo '<li class="royalSlide">
        <div class="celebFixSlider">';

 $i=0;
 foreach ($array as $key => $val)
 {
   $i++; 

    echo '
            <a href="'.$productPath.''.$key.'">
            <img src="'.$val.'" />
    </a>';
   if($i==6){
        echo '</div>
        </li>
        <li class="royalSlide">
              <div class="celebFixSlider">';
    }

 }
```